# Cruisecontrol status with chained batch files

Tags: .net, tfs, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

Once out TFS build gets dropped, I am trying to use Cruisecontrol to move the build to the IIS folder correctly.
I plan to make it run a batch script, which will then call 2-3 other scripts internally using "call" i the batch script.

I need to call the batch files from within each other, because I also pass some parameters from one script to the next.

Can I somehow show a meaningful status message on the cruisecontrol dashboard from the various batchfiles, changing when the next batch file is called?

**A bit about our setup:**

I should add that we are supposed to use TFS for version control and build. TFS has its own dedicated drop server where, once we queue a build, gets built and dropped successfully. This code, we can access via a network shared folder of the application server, where IIS is configured.

Issue is that once the build is complete, we need to finally put the code on our application server, running IIS. Now there are multiple small steps before the code can be made to go live on the environment. Like, we need to add a few dlls by hand andtake backup of the currently running code. So there steps, post the TFS build, are the ones which I am trying to auotmate using CruiseControl.

Comment: Are you using Team Build (TFS) _and_ CruiseControl.Net? If so, why?

Comment: Added a bit more detail about our setup. Please let me know if any other details you may need to understand my query better

Answer (score 0):

I would drop CruiseControl altogether and use Team Build as the sole build controller. With the addition of [TFS Build Extensions](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/), you can easily set up a copy part of the job that will copy from the binaries to a folder anywhere in your domain. You could also benefit from using their Powershell task; without knowing exactly what your batch files do, I'm quite certain that you can replace them with one Powershell script (can be made to run remotely).

Comment: I do not want to deploy application to IIS, every time a build is trigerred. I need to deploy specific build, only when required. So there may be 10 builds made from TFS, but I may want only the last one to be deployed.

Comment: If you know beforehand that a certain build will be deployed on the IIS that deploy step can easily be controlled with a process parameter to Team Build. If it's decided afterwards (depending on the quality of the build), a separate build workflow for the deployment part would be my solution. There is much to gain by having only one build engine to take care of.

Comment: tbergstedt, so can TFS meet my below needs? a) If I need, build AND copy code on another server in IIS folder. b) Before copying code to IIS server, add some additional DLLs to the bin folder as a flat copy c) before copy to IIS folder, take backup of the installed code in IIS folder to a new folder d) Before this copy starts, stop IIS, and start IIS after the copy is done. e)... Can TFS even access another server's folder structure to do all this? f) Also create deployable folders for RDLs and SQl scripts which are checked into TFS

Comment: That's quite some list (I understand why you went for CruiseControl in the first go), but yes; at least if you add TFS Build Extensions to your build configuration. TFS in itself won't be able to do all your tasks, but some Powershell scripting will. The benefit will be that you'll have all your build definitions and tools centralized and configurations in one place.

Comment: powershell script execution is controlled and prohibited on our servers(only for the admins type of thing) :( So I guess that rules it out.

Comment: But isn't the build user administrator on the build server? It is under that account the scripts will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

i think there are only 3 status of CC.Net, Green, Yellow, Red.

What I would do is add an email step to your process that emails whomever at the completion of each step.   You could also setup a twitter account and tweet the status of this using LinqToTwitter or something else.  To do this, you'd probably have to write a console application and call the console app from your bat file that would do the tweeting, but this would be pretty cool.